# How can I use child class methods not defined in a parent class from a parent class pointer?

Tags: c++

I currently have multiple child classes inheriting off of a single parent class. These child classes have radically different member variables and methods. I am trying to upcast instances of these classes and, at the same time, I need to be able to find out which child class each object belongs to and use its unique methods.

Currently, my attempts look something like this:

```
class Parent {
public:
int childNo;
}

class Child1: public Parent {
public:
Child1() {
int childNo = 1;
}
void radicallyDiffentMethod1(){}
}

class Child2: public Parent {
public:
Child2() {
int childNo = 2;
}
void radicallyDiffentMethod2(){}
}

void useChild(Parent* child)
if (child -> childNo == 1){
child -> radicallyDifferntMethod1();
} else {
child -> radicallyDifferentMethod2();
}

Child1* C1 = new Child1;
Child2* c2 = new Child2;

useChild(C1);
useChild(C2);
```

However, this does not work as the Parent class does not define radicallyDifferentMethod1 or radicalllyDifferentMethod2. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I believe the best way is to use `dynamic_cast` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) You attempt to cast the `Parent` pointer to each derived type, and it will return `nullptr` if the pointer is not of the chosen derived type. This only works if all derived types are siblings. Since if you had `Base <-- Derived1 <-- Derived2`, then a dynamic cast of a `Base*` that was actually a `Derived2*` would succeed for both `Derived1*` and `Derived2*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cast through an inheritance hierarchy, you can static_cast the Parent pointer to a child pointer, like so

```
void useChild(Parent* child) 
{
  if (child -> childNo == 1)
  {
    static_cast<Child1*>(child) -> radicallyDiffentMethod1();
  } 
  else 
  {
    static_cast<Child2*>(child) -> radicallyDifferentMethod2();
  }
}
```